# Lambda function boto3 python

Tags: python

When i try to test my lambda functions it updates my dynamodb table however it also gives me extra information i don't want.
I just want the visit numbers.
Does anyone know how to do that?

```
import boto3

import json
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb')
    response = dynamodb.update_item(
    TableName='countercv', 
    Key={
    'url':{'S': "jakejohnson.com"}
    },
    UpdateExpression='SET visits = visits + :inc',
    ExpressionAttributeValues={
    ':inc': {'N': '1'}
},
ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
)

print("UPDATING ITEM")
return(response)
```

Comment: {
  "Attributes": {
    "visits": {
      "N": "101"
    }
  },
  "ResponseMetadata": {
    "RequestId": "8510GO9N2QV9M7IS5545HFRP3NVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG",
    "HTTPStatusCode": 200,
    "HTTPHeaders": {
      "server": "Server",
      "date": "Tue, 21 Jul 2020 12:23:32 GMT",
      "content-type": "application/x-amz-json-1.0",
      "content-length": "37",
      "connection": "keep-alive",
      "x-amzn-requestid": "8510GO9N2QV9M7IS5545HFRP3NVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG",
      "x-amz-crc32": "2452521877"
    },
    "RetryAttempts": 0
  }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
return int(response["Attributes"]["visits"]["N"])
```

Comment: You mean the double quotes? I updated the answer to show how to convert the string to an integer.